# Why Creation of Connections is too expensive in java

Tags: java, connection

I do wonder why creation of connections are termed too expensive,and so the
connection is pooling is maintained.What is in it's back.

Comment: IO, connection usually use network communication which is few orders of magnitude slower than in memory processing

Comment: They are not "too expensive" in general. It is fine to throw it away right after use if you only need it once a minute or something. They are too expensive to throw away if you call them in tight loops though.

Answer (score 3):

> Why Creation of Connections is  expensive in java

Because creating a connection to (say) a remote database involves the execution of millions of machine instructions.  You need to:

- Parse the connection string
- Lookup the hostname for the database in DNS
- Open a TCP/IP network connection
- Establish an SSL/TLS session over the network connection (expensive public key crypto, multiple message exchanges)
- Pass the user credentials to the DB server to be authenticated which may well involve database queries to look up matching user details.

Each exchange of network packets is going to add multiple microseconds ... or more ...

If the database is on the same computer and you talk over a loopback connection or a domain socket, then the network interactions will be faster, but not instantaneous.   You still have syscall overheads, the cost of context switching / process or thread scheduling, etc.  And that's just the "transport" layer.

And if you can dispense with SSL/TLS and encryption, you can shave off a lot more time.

But, I'd be surprised if you would get better than 5 milliseconds on average for establishing an on-machine non-encrypted database connection.

Now multiply that by "lots of new database connections per minute", and the overheads of not recycling connections could be a major concern.

But still, it is worth just measuring it on your own machines with your own databases ...

Comment: I'm not saying I do not agree, but I'd be more afraid of network latency(=simply doing nothing, just waiting), then CPU instructions...